# How to Pop-up,one form fields to other form in HTML

Tags: forms, html

I've two html forms,one is user sign-in form and other is sign-up form,both adjacent each other in one page.Suppose a non-existing user tried to login in my application using some username and password,I'll show error message any how,but at the same time,entered username and password should filled automatically in signup form once error has  been error occurred.By this I can reduce user effort by filling two fields,to implement this,how can I use HTML5 features ?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, on error, you could do a:

```
$('form2#username').val($('form1#username').val());
$('form2#password').val($('form1#password').val());
```

This will move all contents of "username" inside of "form1" to the "username" inside of "form2"

Comment: How can I implement this by using HTML5 feature,not by using jQuery